# How to prove that any infinite algebraic extension of a complete field is never complete?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, extension-field, valuation-theory

My first idea is using Baire category theorem since I thought an infinite algebraic extension should be of countable degree. However, this is wrong, according to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293807/is-the-degree-of-an-infinite-algebraic-extensions-always-countable).

This approach may still work if it is true that **infinite algebraic extensions of complete fields have countable degree**. For instance, infinite algebraic extensions of local fields are of countable degree. I wonder if this is true for general case.

Another possible approach is to generalize the proof in [Bosch, Güntzer, Remmert: Non-Archimedean Analysis](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783540125464), Lemma 1, Section 3.4.3. Where they use [Krasner's Lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krasner%27s_lemma) to prove that if the algebraic closure of a complete field is of infinite degree then it is not complete. However, Krasner's Lemma only works for separable elements, so I wonder if this proof can be used for **infinite purely inseparable extensions of complete fields**.

Answer (score 11):

The separable case does indeed follow from Krasner's lemma: see [here](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/cheltsov/gnt/hw4.pdf).

I think I have a counterexample to the purely inseparable case. The idea is that we adjoin all possible $p$-th roots of elements in the ground field $K$, where $p$ is the characteristic, resulting in a new field $L$ to which the original valuation extends uniquely (because $L/K$ is algebraic). Then all $p$-th powers of $\ell\in L$ lie in $K$, essentially by the freshman's dream, and in fact the map $L\rightarrow K$ given by $\ell\rightarrow\ell^p$ is a uniformly continuous homeomorphism with uniformly continuous inverse. Therefore, $L$ is complete as long as $K$ is.

We just need to make sure that we can do this with $K$ a complete field and have enough $p$-th roots to make $[L:K]=\infty$. To ensure this, we'll just adjoin a bunch of dummy variables in forming $K$, and the $p$-th roots of these dummy variables will be linearly independent. We begin with the field of rational functions in infinitely many variables over $\mathbb{F}_p, $ namely $\mathbb{F}_p(x_1,x_2,\dots).$ As norm we take the one induced by $|x_1|=\frac{1}{2}$ and $|R(x_2,x_3,\dots)|=1$ for all rational functions $R$, essentially the $x_1$-adic valuation. We still need to complete this, and its easy to see that the completion is the field of infinite Laurent series in $x_1$, expressions of the form $\sum\limits_{k=-n}^{\infty} (x_1^k)R_k(x_2,x_3,\dots)$ where $R_k$ are arbitrary rational functions. This completion is our ground field $K$.

After adjoining all $p$-th roots to form $L$ as described above, we just need to check that $(x_i)^{\frac{1}{p}}$ are linearly independent over $K$; this will show that $[L:K]=\infty$. Well, this is pretty easy: assume not! Then taking $p$-th powers and using the freshman's dream again, we get a non-trivial identity of the form $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m x_i P_i(x_1^p,x_2^p,\dots)=0$ for $P_i \in K$. We can consider the smallest $j$ such that one of the $x_iP_i(x_1^p,x_2^p,\dots)$ series has a non-zero $x_1^j$-term. Taking the $x_1^j$-coefficient of our identity we have $0=\sum\limits_{i=2}^m x_i S_i(x_2^p,x_3^p,\dots)$ where $S_i$ is the $x_1^j$-coefficient of $P_i$ (it's clear that the $x_1P_1(x_1^p,x_2^P,\dots$) doesn't contribute an $x_1^j$ term; if it did, it would be the only one to do so!). The $S_i$ are rational functions, so by clearing denominators they are wlog polynomials, since we have finitely many $S_i$ each using only finitely many variables. But now the monomial terms clearly don't match up at all, so we have a contradiction, and we've established linear independence.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how to generalize the proof in Bosch-Güntzer-Remmert's book. The same goes for the Baire category approach, which indeed seem very natural.
I think however that [this should work.](http://math.mit.edu/~swshin/Fall11/Lee.PDF) The argument is not mine. I will basically write it out, in case anyone deletes the .pdf in the future. Any errors that occurs in this post are due to me and I would recommend reading the .pdf above since it is written in a more coherent way than this post.

Note that there is no restriction to consider infinite fields. I will assume throughout that the valuation is non-archimedean (the archimedean case is of course trivial).

Let $K$ be any infinite field and consider an infinite algebraic extension $L$ of $K.$ Then you have that $|L| = |K|.$This is discussed [in this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/604757/cardinality-of-algebraic-extensions-of-an-infinite-field/604788#604788).

From this, I claim that if $K \subset L$ is an infinite algebraic extension and $K$ and $L$ are complete, then $|K| < |L|,$ which gives a contradiction.

Indeed, let us take a (countably) infinite linearly independent subset $\{x_i\}$ of $L$ over $K.$ Now, we can assume that we choose $x_i$'s such that $|x_i|/2 > |x_{i+1}|.$ Then we have that the sums $$\omega_{\epsilon} = \sum \epsilon_i x_i $$ where $\epsilon_i \in \{0,1\}$ are in $L$ and further are distinct.

That all sums $\omega_{\epsilon}$ are in $L$ is clear - the terms form a null-sequence and for non-archimedean fields this enough. Further, let us take two  sums $\omega_{\epsilon} = \sum_i \epsilon_i x_i$ and $\omega_{\epsilon'} = \sum_i \epsilon'_i x_i$ where for some $i$ $\epsilon_i \neq \epsilon'_i.$ Then if we consider the difference $\omega_{\epsilon}-\omega_{\epsilon'} = \sum_i (\epsilon_i-\epsilon'_i)x_i$ there is a smallest $i_0$ such that $\epsilon_{i_0} \neq \epsilon'_{i_0}.$ Then we have that $$|(\epsilon_{i_0} - \epsilon'_{i_0})x_{i_0}| = |\sum_{k=i_0}^\infty (\epsilon_k-\epsilon'_k) x_k| < |\sum_{k=1}^\infty (\epsilon_{i_0}-\epsilon'_{i_0})x_{i_0}/2^k = |(\epsilon_{i_0} - \epsilon'_{i_0})x_{i_0}| .$$ This yields a contradiction and thus all the $\omega_{\epsilon}$ are distinct. So using these $\omega_\epsilon$ we see that $|K| < 2^{|K|} \leq |L|$ which is a contradiction.

Comment: Why the number of those sums $\omega_\epsilon$ is $2^{|K|}$? I think it is only $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @X.GatMath That was my first thought as well, but what if we instead consider the lines  $K \omega_e$ we get for each $K$? Maybe that doesn't make a difference on further thought - this should exist whenever we have a countable basis. So maybe the proof above doesn't work?Can we sum over non-countable indexing sets in a coherent way?